How to download generated package from GitHub Actions job?
I used cmake, C++. Cmake generates package:
Run cmake --build . --target package
[ 50%] Built target helloworld
[100%] Built target HW1Test_run
Run CPack packaging tool...
CPack: Create package using DEB
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: helloworld
CPack: - Install project: helloworld []
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: /home/runner/work/c_plus_otus/c_plus_otus/helloworld-0.0.37-Linux.deb generated.

I need to download /home/runner/work/c_plus_otus/c_plus_otus/helloworld-0.0.37-Linux.deb file.

Do you actually store that file anywhere (e.g. as a build artifact, https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact)? Runners are ephemeral.
